# What does this python warning mean: Setuptools is replacing distutils

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to use python3.11's help utility to get a list of all modules, I get the following error:

```
Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help()

Welcome to Python 3.11's help utility!

If this is your first time using Python, you should definitely check out
the tutorial on the internet at https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/.

Enter the name of any module, keyword, or topic to get help on writing
Python programs and using Python modules.  To quit this help utility and
return to the interpreter, just type "quit".

To get a list of available modules, keywords, symbols, or topics, type
"modules", "keywords", "symbols", or "topics".  Each module also comes
with a one-line summary of what it does; to list the modules whose name
or summary contain a given string such as "spam", type "modules spam".

help> modules

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

test_sqlite3: testing with version '2.6.0', sqlite_version '3.42.0'
C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_distutils_hack\__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
```

Tried to check the path but could not find any.

Comment: It's a warning, but it looks to be related to a library module, so I believe it is an issue for the maintainers of the sqlite3 module